# How can I wait for all data to be written before the serial port connection is terminated

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I need to send data from my QT application via serial port. I am trying to send data in this way.

```
void productDetail::on_detailSaveBtn_clicked()
{
    if (!serial.isOpen())
    {
        if (serial.begin(QString("COM3"), 9600, 8, 0, 1, 0, false))
        {
            serial.send(ui->productDesp->text().toLatin1());
            serial.end();
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it, serial connection closes without writing all data. I think closing the serial port after waiting for all the data to be written  can solve my problem. How can I verify that all data is written before the serial port close?

QT 5.15.2
Windows

Comment: what type is `serial` ? what does its `send` method return? Typically there is some way to know how many bytes have been send

Comment: Assuming you are using [`QSerialPort`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) you can check via [`bytesToWrite`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#bytesToWrite).

Comment: Yes I'm using `QSerialPort` 
How can I use it in function. Can you show me an example please. @Aconcagua

Comment: `bool Serial::send(QString message)
{
    if (this->serialDevice->isOpen() && this->serialDevice->isWritable())
    {
        this->serialDevice->write(message.toStdString().c_str());
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
`
This is my send function @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: Off-topic – please don't do `if(condition) return true; else return false;`, just have `return condition;` instead...

Comment: For closing the port I'd connect a slot to the signal [`bytesWritten`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesWritten) and within there I'd check how many bytes are yet left to write (see previous comment) – if none left, then you can safely close the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wait a few time so a portion of data can be written. Check if any left  with while loop and repeat the process.

```
serial.send(ui->productDesp->text().toLatin1());
while(serial.bytesToWrite()){
    serial.waitForBytesWritten(20);
}
serial.end();
```